# Flask - Write temp CSV to be read by D3

Tags: csv, d3.js, flask, python-3.7

I am currently trying to write a CSV file in Flask using Pandas which then should be read by D3.js. However, the CSV file is not being generated and I get the errors `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test.csv 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` and `Uncaught ProgressEvent` which from what I gather is because the CSV file cannot be found.

I have tried different solutions, namely attempting to write a CSV using `dataframe.to_csv(path)` but the file is never generated and no errors were returned.

I have also tried using the buffer and Flask's inbuilt `send_file` method to create a temporary CSV file to be read by `d3.csv(...)`. However, the file never seems to be generated and I get the aforementioned `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test.csv 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` and `Uncaught ProgressEvent` errors in the browser console. Below are snippets of my current code.

**Python**

```
def get_d3_data(doc_id):

    ...

    buffer = StringIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(buffer, encoding='utf-8')
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(buffer,
              attachment_filename="test.csv",
              mimetype='text/csv')

def rank(doc_id):
    ...
    get_d3_data(doc_id)

    return render_template('rank.html', ...)
```

**Javascript**

*Following code from https://gist.github.com/mbostock/6fead6d1378d6df5ae77bb6a719afcb2*

```
...

d3.csv("test.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
        for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
        d.total = t;
        return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
        z.domain(data.columns.slice(1));
        g.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
                .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
                .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
                .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.date) + x.bandwidth(); })
                .padAngle(0.01)
                .padRadius(innerRadius));
        var label = g.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + ((x(d.date) + x.bandwidth() / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + innerRadius + ",0)"; });
        label.append("line")
            .attr("x2", -5)
            .attr("stroke", "#000");
        label.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return (x(d.date) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI / 2) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "rotate(90)translate(0,16)" : "rotate(-90)translate(0,-9)"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.date; });
        var yAxis = g.append("g")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        var yTick = yAxis
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(y.ticks(5).slice(1))
            .enter().append("g");
        yTick.append("circle")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("r", y);
        yTick.append("text")
            .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d); })
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5)
            .text(y.tickFormat(5, "s"));
        yTick.append("text")
            .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d); })
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .text(y.tickFormat(5, "s"));
        yAxis.append("text")
            .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(y.ticks(5).pop()); })
            .attr("dy", "-1em")
            .text("Population");
        var legend = g.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data.columns.slice(1).reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(-40," + (i - (data.columns.length - 1) / 2) * 20 + ")"; });
        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .attr("fill", z);
        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
    });

...
```

I have also tried transferring the CSV data as a string to the Javascript code and attempted to read the data using `d3.csvParse(...)` (which works). However, I have yet to convert the `d3.csv(...)` code into a working `d3.csvParse(...)` code.

**CSV I should be getting which I get from `var rankingscsv= '{{ rankingscsv|tojson|safe }}';`**

```
"date,fours,fives,sixes,sevens,eights,nines
2019-01-01,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-02,3,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-03,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-04,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-05,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-06,0,1,0,0,0,0
2019-01-07,1,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-08,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-09,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-10,1,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-11,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-12,0,2,0,0,0,0
2019-01-13,2,0,1,0,0,0
2019-01-14,2,1,0,0,0,0
2019-01-15,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-16,2,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-17,2,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-18,3,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-19,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-20,2,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-21,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-22,0,0,1,0,0,0
2019-01-23,2,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-24,0,1,0,0,0,0
2019-01-25,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-26,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-27,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-28,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-29,0,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-30,1,0,0,0,0,0
2019-01-31,1,0,1,0,0,0
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first fragment tries to combine CSV and HTML

```
def rank(doc_id):
    ...
    send_file(...)
    return render_template(...)
```

Tempting, but you'll need to do one at a time. You can achieve the effect you're after (getting CSV to D3) by instead doing something like

```
def rank(doc_id):
    return render_template('rank.html', doc_id=doc_id, ...)
```

Then rework the JavaScript that's embedded in rank.html to pass along `doc_id` when it requests CSV.

```
d3.csv("/csv/{{doc_id}}", ...
```

A new route does the rest

```
@app.route('/csv/<doc_id>')
def csv(doc_id):
    ...
    return send_file(buffer, mimetype='text/csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That got me a step closer. However, the created CSV file is still empty. When I add a `console.log(data);` after 'if (error) throw error;', I get an empty array '[columns: Array(0)]'.

Comment: That's good news, since that's likely a more easily isolatable problem. See if you can reduce that to a small test case, and post it as a new question.